# Having issues in assigning mysql datatypes

Tags: mysql, datatypes

I am working first time with database. I had never inserted data into database.  I want to insert below csv into mysql database. But I facing issues with data types. What type of data type I should assign to the variables.

```
   "cell","id","too","Issue","Valid","DPT","RH","TMP","U","V"
"1",1,22383,"2015-01-15 00:00:00 GMT","2015-01-15 12:00:00 GMT",267.800018310547,91.5999984741211,269.040008544922,-0.529999971389771,-1.78999996185303
"2",2,24532,"2015-01-15 00:00:00 GMT","2015-01-15 12:00:00 GMT",272.600006103516,88.5,274.259979248047,-1.58999991416931,-0.239999994635582
"3",3,23936,"2015-01-15 00:00:00 GMT","2015-01-15 12:00:00 GMT",271,88.2000045776367,272.72998046875,-0.429999977350235,-1.01999998092651
```

Could anyone help me in figuring out the data types of the columns?

I have assigned datatypes below but I am getting so many values while inserting data:

```
CREATE TABLE `raster_cell_data` (
  `cell` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `too` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `Issue` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Valid` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DPT` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RH` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TMP` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `U` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `V` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am loading data using the below command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\vkaushik\\Desktop\\Temp.csv'
    INTO TABLE raster_cell_data
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

`Getting Error 1234: out of the range` for many variables while loading. And only 101 rows are getting inserted out of 901.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess GMT is making this issue. Try it again removing GMT from date time value. This may help you

Comment: How are you importing the CSV file (**C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues) into your table? I'm asking because your data is not comma separated. Which tool/program are you using? Supply as much information as possible by [editing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/191950/edit) your question and adding the specifics.

Comment: Is this tab separated data? That's fine - take a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loading-tables.html). What is it, exactly, that you are measuring with a precision of 10e-7 Celsius?

Comment: It seems like you may need to [merge your two accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts), @leopard.

Comment: As a general tip: look at rows that are not getting loaded. Look throughout the file, in case the data you're being handed changes at some point. Also, consider loading to a staging table, setting all values to `nvarchar` (`varchar` is OK if you're sure that you aren't getting Unicode data), and perform appropriate conversions to load the data to its ultimate destination.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of " GMT" in the fly, use @variables and SET.  Something like

```
LOAD ...   
    ... ,
    ( cell, id, too, @issue, ... )
    SET issue = LEFT(@issue, 19)
    ...;
```